# Debian Testing not booting fully (display manager not loading)

Tags: debian, boot, login

Every time I boot my (fresh) Debian install with `gnome-core` with a couple of the packages added that come with `gnome`. I installed Debian without a desktop environment which boots and reaches the login console fine, after which I installed GNOME. After rebooting, the system hangs after the wall of dmesg. The reason why I believe it's the display manager is because I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[number]</kbd> to another TTY and can login fine, but TTY completely locks up and never loads the DM. It should be running GDM. I can't get systemctl to start GDM either, and running `startx` just hangs until it gives up and shows my prompt again. I've reinstalled twice just to be sure it isn't an edge case. I successfully ran Debian Testing a few months ago without a hitch, but that was with Cinnamon and lightdm, so it's an entirely different situation.

dmesg: https://pastebin.com/B0zL6waq

Xorg log: https://pastebin.com/f61p20t8

Answer (score 0):

In your `dmesg` output, I found this:

```
[    1.083529] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[    1.083620] [drm:amdgpu_pci_probe [amdgpu]] *ERROR* amdgpu requires firmware installed
[    1.083646] See https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware for information about missing firmware
```

You'll need to install the `firmware-amd-graphics` package, which is in the `non-free` part of Debian repository (because AMD does not give the source code of the firmware to anyone, so it's not compliant with the ideals of Free Software).